# Warning 312: Nested union not currently supported (ignored)

Tags: c++, string, go, swig, unions

I am getting the following Warning while running the swig interface file Warning 312: Nested union not currently supported (ignored). I was able to suppress the warning. But I need the nested union for computation

SWIG Version 3.0.12

Below is the Interface file(example.swigcxx)

```
%module(directors="1") example
%header %{
#include "./include/DataType.h"
#include "./include/Struct.h"
#include "./include/InterfaceBase.h"
%}

/* Parse the header files to generate wrappers */
%include "std_string.i"

%feature("director") IGTAQTSCallbackBase;

%include "./include/DataType.h"
%include "./include/Struct.h"
%include "./include/InterfaceBase.h"
```

struct.h

```
struct  DCE_BuySellLevelInfo
{
  double              Price;                 
  unsigned long long  Volume;                 
  unsigned long long  ImplyQty;              
};

struct DCEL2_Quotation
{
  int                 TradeDate;                        
  int                 Time;                               
  char                Symbol[SYMBOL_LEN];              
  unsigned int        RoutineNo;    

  unsigned int        MBLQuotBuyNum;    
  union
  {
    DCE_BuySellLevelInfo3     BuyLevel[LEVEL_FIVE];  
    struct  
     {
        double              BuyPrice01;       
        unsigned long long  BuyVolume01;        
        unsigned long long  BidImplyQty01;     
        double              BuyPrice02;      
        unsigned long long  BuyVolume02;    
        unsigned long long  BidImplyQty02;   
     };
   };

  unsigned int                MBLQuotSellNum;      
  union
  {
    DCE_BuySellLevelInfo3    SellLevel[LEVEL_FIVE];     
    struct  
    {
        double              SellPrice01;
        unsigned long long  SellVolume01; 
        unsigned long long  AskImplyQty01;
        double              SellPrice02;  
        unsigned long long  SellVolume02;  
        unsigned long long  AskImplyQty02; 

    };
  };    
  double  Delta;                
};
```

swig -go -cgo -c++ -intgosize 64 example.swigcxx

`Struct.h:1: Warning 312: Nested union not currently supported (ignored).`

Comment: You could change the header such that no nested structs or unions appear. If you cannot change the header, you could create a new header and make a simple wrapper with the necessary typecasts